# Json cpp asCstring() returns empty cstring when stored in variable

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I'm using Json-cpp to parse my config file and I get som weird behavior with [asCString()](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#5b7da48b163bcec63b1424f1608b7da6).. Can anyone explain why output of 2 is empty?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define JSON_IS_AMALGAMATION
#include "json/json.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    std::ifstream config("dev.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!reader.parse(config, root, false)) {
      cout << "Could not parse json" << endl;
      return 1;
    }
    std::string str = root["redis"].get("host", "localhost").asString();
    const char* cstr = root["redis"].get("host", "localhost").asCString();
    cout << "1:" << str << endl;
    cout << "2:" << cstr << endl;
    cout << "3:" << std::string(root["redis"].get("host", "localhost").asCString()) << endl;
    config.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c++ -o test test.cpp jsoncpp.cpp
1:127.0.0.2
2:
3:127.0.0.2
```

My json data:

```
{ "redis": { "host": "127.0.0.2", "port": 6379 } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `root["redis"].get("host", "localhost")` or `root["redis"]` returns a `Value`, not a reference to a `Value`. That `Value` object will live until the end of the expression, in the case of `2` the temporary `Value` object will be destroyed, leaving `cstr` as a dangling pointer. The behaviour is undefined when dereferencing a dangling pointer.

In the case of `1`, the `str` is a copy of the `std::string` returned by `asString()`.

In the case of `3`, the temporary `Value` will survive until the end of the expression (the `;`) allowing the `const char*` returned by `asCString()` to be successfully processed.

To solve, either:

- change the type of `cstr` to `std::string` and it will copy the returned `const char*`, or
- Make of a copy of the `Value` returned by `get()` and query it rather than `root[]`.

EDIT:

Based on this [source](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/json__value_8cpp_source.html), all variants of `Value.get()` return a `Value`. So the cause is as described.